# HtmlAgilityPack GetElementby Name

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I using  HtmlAgilityPack

```
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument DocToParse = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
  DocToParse.LoadHtml(HtmlIn);
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode InputNode = DocToParse.GetElementbyId(IDToGet)
```

This works fine for  element that have Id like

```
<input type="hidden" id="nsv" value="y">
```

But elements that i need dont have Id only name

```
<input type="hidden" name="Pass" value="106402333">
<input type="hidden" name="User" value="145">
```

sow i can't use

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode InputNode = DocToParse.GetElementbyId(IDToGet)
```

and there is no method GetElementbyName,sow any one know how i can get element by Name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use XPath selector:

```
var nodes = DocToParse.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@name='" + NameToGet + "']");
```

Comment: find it --   value=   nodes[0].Attributes[1].Value;